# How to access app to save data from outside the app

Tags: ios, swift, parsing

I would like be able to to access my App from Safari.

Example: User is on Adidas.com and taps the "share-button". My app should appear next to all the other apps and if the user taps on my app, the app should parse the website for the products name, price and image.

Here is a screenshot from "Wishupon" that is basically doing the exact same thing I would like to achieve:

[image]

**What answer I am looking for:**

I am looking for someone who could tell me the different steps I have to take to get this done. No specific code, just some general info.

I don't really know how that "process" is called so I don't know how to google it. Tried things like "Access app from Safari share button" but that didn't get me any answers.. Grateful for every help :)

Comment: You need to create a share sheet extension

Comment: @Paulw11 I thought thats for acutally sharing something from your App. But I would like to do it the other way around

Comment: No, your app provides a share sheet extension to let other apps share data *to* it

Comment: alright got it, share extension is actually what I need, thanks. Do you have a good tutorial by any chance? Can't find a good one and I am quite struggling to get it done...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a function of the `UIActivityController` and a need to subclass `UIActivity`.

I believe this [article from Paul Hudson](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/118/uiactivityviewcontroller-by-example) on the `UIActivityViewController` will help you. (I know links are discouraged, but the section is lengthy and I don't want to plagiarize)

Comment: I did everything in that article but that is how to share data from your app to some other app. Like I said in the comments that's not what I am looking for. I want to access the App from outside the app. But my App is not being displayed there

Comment: Oh I'm sorry - I had thought that the section titled "Adding a custom action" was for doing exactly that, but upon closer inspection, I think you're right. What you're looking for might be solved by implemented deep links/using URL Types and implementing schemes... I'm not sure if that is useful for things like you're trying or just for sharing files, though.